# using a javascript function to show/hide a collapsed bootstrap item

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, show-hide

i want to use javascript function for show/hide a div id="collapse-item" that i've realized using bootstrap.

for example like this:

```
function showCollapse(){
    document.getElementById("collapse-item").collapse.show="true";
}
```

or similar..
I don't want to use jquery.
Is it possible? can someone explain to me why?

thanks

Comment: show: `document.getElementById("collapse-item").style.display = "block"`; hide: `document.getElementById("collapse-item").style.display = "none"`;

Comment: pay attention if you are using `flexbox` then the show should be: `document.getElementById("collapse-item").style.display = "flex"`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it is toggleing between `true` and `false` just like a on/off switch.. one button and 2 outputs..

here is the code

```
<button onclick="toggle()"> 
        Toggle Bool 
</button> 
<script> 
        let testBool = true; 
        console.log('Default value of bool is', testBool); 
      
        function toggle() { 
            testBool = !testBool; 
            console.log('Toggled bool is', testBool); 
        }
    </script>
```

Check the console log to see the output

Now use `testBool` in a `if` statement or `ternary Operator` to hide and unhide any or all elements on the page